# How exactly we need to use the type cast?

Tags: java, casting

```
void test() {
    String s1 = "1";
    //int i1 = int(s1); -- compilation error
    int i1 = Integer.parseInt(s1);

    long l1 = 1;
    int i2 = (int) l1;
}
```

When to use `Integer.parseInt` to convert to `Integer` and when to use only `int` to convert to `Integer`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875544/beginner-java-question-about-integer-parseint-and-casting Should solve your problem

Comment: A string can't be *cast* to an integer.  But a string containing integer characters can be *parsed*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Casting take place from child to parent (downcast) or vise versa (upcast):

```
class A extends B
B b = (B)(new A());
```

or in case of interfaces:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> myArrayList = (ArrayList)myList;
```

or between primitives - your case.

You can decide that you want to convert `long` to `int` or vise versa.

Parsing is somehow different. You take a `String` which has nothing to do with numeric types and declare that you would like to `try` to parse it into a number.

You take such decision by deep belief that that `String` has digits only (in any of the numeric systems up to base 16) and you want to use that number as a numeric variable.

That mechanism is widely described in [specification chapter 5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html). Casting in terms of primitives can stand for one of two operations: *Widening primitive conversions* or *Narrowing primitive conversions*.

#### Widening primitive conversions

There are 19 possible widening primitive conversions. Widening means going from smaller type to larger.

```
+-----------+-------+------+-------+-------+--------+
|           | short |  int |  long | float | double |
| short ->  |       | x    | x     | x     | x      |
| int ->    |       |      | x     | x     | x      |
| long ->   |       |      |       | x     | x      |
| float ->  |       |      |       |       | x      |
| double -> |       |      |       |       |        |
+-----------+-------+------+-------+-------+--------+
```

You can read about the consequences [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2).

#### Narrowing primitive conversions

```
+-----------+------+------+-------+------+-------+-------+--------+
|           | byte | char | short |  int |  long | float | double |
| byte ->   |      |      |       |      |       |       |        |
| char ->   |      |      |       |      |       |       |        |
| short ->  | x    | x    |       |      |       |       |        |
| int ->    | x    | x    | x     |      |       |       |        |
| long ->   | x    | x    | x     | x    |       |       |        |
| float ->  | x    | x    | x     | x    | x     |       |        |
| double -> | x    | x    | x     | x    | x     | x     |        |
+-----------+------+------+-------+------+-------+-------+--------+
```

The consequences are described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3).

#### Casting conversion

Casting conversions are described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.4). They include all possible casts including *String conversion* which is used when using `+` operand for String and non-string.

Answer (score 0):

`int` is a *primitive type*. It therefore does not have any *constructors*, let alone one from a `java.lang.String`. So `int i1 = int(s1);` makes no sense.

Luckily the boxed analogue `Integer` contains a static method `parseInt` that yield an `int` and takes a `java.lang.String`. Exactly what you want!

Answer (score 0):

`Integer.parseInt` is to parse a `String` and create a value of the expected type, it's not actually casting in this case.

Casting is when converting an instance of one class to another (or a primitive type to another)